# Can we use URL to point to a particular paragraph of word document on SharePoint?

Tags: office-integration, word

We have a SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm. After upload the word document to SharePoint we can provide a URL to users so that we can directly open the document.

Can we also build a URL so that the user can directly jump to particular paragraph (like an anchor) of the word document?

Answer (score 1):

I am afriad, you cant get this done. Their is no such OOTB functionality in SharePoint which allow tag/anchor/bookmark url within a document.

You can try to create index/ table of content in the document and user can browse it after opening the document.